# Displaying dropdown attribute in Compare page in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I'd like to display the color dropdown attribute in my the compare window of products in Magento frontend. I know how to display the selected value of the dropdown but I'd like the actual dropdown to be displayed in frontend, particularly in the compare products window. How can I implement this? Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of attributes using

```
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
->getAttributeRawValue
($productId, 'attribute_code', $storeId);
```

After getting these values depending upon your requirement , you can edit in phtml using enabling template path hints

Comment: I don't think I understood your answer well. Is this supposed to return the values of the dropdown or the actual dropdown in the frontend? I tried following your example but all I got was a false when I tried var_dump. I also tried echo but no results appeared.

Comment: you need to call the correct attribute code ? inside the function ?